# JQuery Adding and removing a slash

Tags: jquery, hyperlink, slash

jQuery code is

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  if (navigator.appVersion.indexOf("Win") != -1) {
   // Computers runs windows
    $("a[href$='.pdf']").each(function() {
        this.href = this.href.replace("Volumes", "KP01DS0194TG");
    });
  }
  if (navigator.appVersion.indexOf("Mac") != -1) {
    // computer is a Mac
    $("a[href$='.pdf']").each(function() {
        this.href = this.href.replace("KP01DS0194TG", "Volumes");
    });
  }
});
```

I need it to remove a slash on the windows side , how can I go about it?

My Link is as follows `href="file:///KP01DS0194TG/Quotes/Scanning/brother/Jobsheets/job no 12538.pdf">12538</a>` thats fine for mac's with volumes , however i Need it as 'file://KP01DS0194TG' for pc's , how can I remove that slash?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you have a link such as:

```
<a href="file:///[somelink]">Click Here</a>
```

and you want to remove one slash, use:

```
$('a').each(function() {
    var theLink = $(this).attr('href');// get href
    theLink = theLink.replace(/\/\/\//g,'//');// replace 3 slashes with 2
    $(this).attr('href', theLink);
});
```

Comment: Of course you can condense this significantly, I just split them up to show what each line did and for clarity.

Comment: thanks that looks great! however - do you know how I'd be able to incorporate that into my current Jquery - as unfortunately I need to keep the original how it is.

Comment: Yes, add the replace section I wrote after your first replace. Like so: this.href = this.href.replace("Volumes", "KP01DS0194TG").replace(/\/\/\//g,'//');

Comment: Thats great thanks alot!! ,
How ever my last thing (hopefully you can help with this too ) .
on windows it makes 2 slashes , however on mac it keeps the three but wont change it to Volumes - any idea?

Comment: Try changing your mac line to read as follows: this.href = this.href.replace(/\/\/\//g, '///Volumes/'); or if you need to change any portion of the href to include something, just match it in the first part of replace, and include your change in the second part. There are many great places for learning regular expressions, or regex, just Google it and bookmark references you understand and wish to keep handy.

Comment: Thanks , im having problem with my coding again , Ill just have to try and figure it out now >< haha , but thanks - you've solved this question (: